# What is the difference between ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT() and ON_WM_CTLCOLOR() in VS2008?

Tags: mfc, windows-ce

The question is like this:
I write a windows application in VS2005, building success. Then I transfer it to VS2008, when I build the program, there will be an error messsage shows:
 error C4867: 'CGroupBox::CtlColor': function call missing argument list; use '&CGroupBox::CtlColor' to create a pointer to member
the message map is as follows:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGroupBox, CButton)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CGroupBox)
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
//ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
```

END_MESSAGE_MAP()

the function is is as follows:

```
HBRUSH CGroupBox::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
GetParent()->Invalidate();
return NULL;
}
```

but if I change to the ON_WM_CTLCOLOR() ,I can get a successful build.

Comment: Once you have created a new MFC control class, you can define message handlers for it. Reflected message handlers allow your control class to handle its own messages before the message is received by the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is because the signature of the message handler doesn't match the signature you're using. Look up the signatures for ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT() and ON_WM_CTLCOLOR() on MSDN to get the correct ones.

As to the question in your title, some controls normally send their notification messages to their parent. Which is inconvenient, because every time you re-use that control, you need to change its parent window. Therefore MFC has 'reflection' support, which is basically a way of saying 'when you receive a notification from a child control, first try bouncing it back to that control to see if that control knows how to deal with it itself.'

Read the details on https://web.archive.org/web/20101229015404/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd(v=vs.80).aspx .

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and as you can see from the link Roel provided, the original poster DID have the correct signature.

Turns out this is a bug in MFC itself.  Find ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT in afxmsg_.h and you'll notice that CtlColor is missing the "&" before it.  I guess the older compilers didn't mind.  Add the "&" to make it "&CtlColor" and the error is fixed.

Alternatively, if you don't like changing the official headers, you could #under ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT in your own code and define it again properly.

I notice many other (maybe all?) reflected messages in that file have the same problem too.